# Strange SpriteKit + UIDynamics Bug

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior

So I'm developing a game using SpriteKit. And to make the game more interesting I decided to use UIDynamicAnimator to add some physics to the UIKit elements within my game. Everything works great except there is one major problem. The moment I alloc/init a UIDynamicAnimator like so:

```
animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
```

The physics bodies in my game get completely offset. Even if I don't specify a reference view the physics still get offset.

What's strange is that i'm creating the UIDynamicAnimator in a completely separate ViewController so it's not like it's sharing the same reference view or something like that.

**Update**: Even the act of simply creating a UIDynamicItemBehavior like so:

```
UIDynamicBehavior* a = [[UIDynamicBehavior alloc] init];
```

messes up my scene's physics.

I'm assuming this is an internal bug with the physics engine that SpriteKit and UIDynamics share.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: In the WWDC 2013 video [Getting Started with UIKit Dynamics](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?include=206#206) Apple discusses when one might use one and when one might use the other. Clearly Apple views them as alternatives (which use the same physics engine behind the scenes, see [Simulating Physics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html)), not as two technologies you'd use at the same time.

Comment: DUDE I HAVE THE SAME EXACT BUG

Comment: this bug is still around in 2022 HOW LMAO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found a pretty hacky solution. All you need to do is use the UIDynamics framework in some way before presenting your SKScene. For example, simply running this one line of code before presenting your scene will remove the weird physics bug caused by simultaneously using SpriteKit and UIDynamics at the same time:

```
UIDynamicBehavior* a = [[UIDynamicBehavior alloc] init];
```

I'm assuming internally this prepares the physics engine in such a way that sprite kit physics will behave normally. Unfortunately I do not trust this solution because it might not work one day and my entire game would suffer because of it.

So as an alternative to the UIDynamics framework I've decided to just use UIView Animation to replicate some of the interesting physics effects that I got with the UIDynamics Framework.

**EDIT FOR IOS 8**
According to doctordoder, this bug still exists in iOS 8, and this workaround still works.

Comment: HAHAHAH WTF why the hell does this work? It fixed my bug completely too!

Comment: @doctordoder Yes it's a very odd workaround. I want to test this out on iOS 8 and see if the bug is fixed yet. I'll edit my answer to include that when I get a chance.

Comment: The bug was actually occurring for me in iOS 8, and your fix still works.

Comment: @doctordoder Oh really. Ok i'll update answer with this information.

Comment: Same bug in iOS 9 and the solution is not working (at least not for impulses etc.)

Comment: @JakubTruhlář Aw that's unfortunate, thanks for the update.

Comment: Is there still no solution for that?

Comment: @JakubTruhlář Unfortunately none that I know of.

Comment: this kind of works for me in iOS 16, it adjusts the spritekit physics to how they would be after navigating to a view with uikit dynamics. I'd prefer to find a way to re-isolate the two frameworks

Answer (score 0):

**Note that in iOS 9: the @Epic Byte's solution still do the half workaround.**

It starts the physics engine earlier (before we `initialize` `SpriteKit` game etc.) but unfortunately it **mixes it up**.

And `allocation` and `init` the `UIDynamicAnimator` during the `SpriteKit` game will cause the `physicsWorld` and it's properties like `gravity` act differently.

Also it seems like the `physicsWorld` is removed for a short time (switching engines?) during `UIDynamicAnimator` initialization.

**Conclusion:**

- **Alloc and init `UIDynamicAnimator` asap and handle your physics world differently e.g. call**

  `[UIDynamicAnimator new];` in delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

**or**

- **Do not mix the UIKit Dynamics and SpriteKit**