# Is UIKit Dynamics built on top of the SpriteKit framework?

Tags: ios, macos, sprite-kit, uikit-dynamics

We need to port UIKit Dynamics to MacOS, we already ported it using the low level Box2D C++ library but I wondering if the porting could be easier to do and better to maintain using SpriteKit on Mac.

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing

Comment: No one knows for a fact whether it will be easier to port with Sprite Kit or not, especially not without knowing the app's requirements. Voted to close since answers are likely to be subjective, plus the question in the title requires knowledge of how closed source framework internals work.

Comment: Just want to add that UIKit Dynamics and SpriteKit are definitely related internally. I had an odd bug once when I was using UIDynamics with SpriteKit. I ended up not using UIDynamics because it was interfering with the sprite-kit physics simulation. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21651807/2158465