# SpriteKit and UIDynamics together are acting strange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit-dynamics

I'm trying to use `UIDynamics` in one view controller and when I push another view controller that contains SKView with scene that uses physics, it acts weird. If I disable `UIDynamics` on previous controller and comment this line:

```
_animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.viewGround];
```

physics on the next view controller works well.

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe it could help in some way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651807/strange-spritekit-uidynamics-bug

Comment: I tried this solution, but no luck.